# Is there an idiom for "something tasty/good/nice, but not nutritious/substantial"?

Tags: idioms

Something like "good soup, but no meat"

update: not necessarily food related

Comment: does it have to be food related?

Comment: There's a tempest in a teapot = making a big deal from nothing. The Italians say a lot of smoke, but were's the roast?

Comment: @Cally Please visit this link to merge the two accounts you made: https://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 4):

TFD(idioms):

> **[junk food](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/junk+food)**
>   Prepackaged snack food that is high in calories but low in nutritional value;  also, anything attractive but negligible in
>   value.
>   For example, Nell loves potato chips and other junk food, or
>   When I'm sick in bed I often resort to TV soap operas and similar junk
>   food.
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer.
>   Copyright © 2003, 1997 by The Christine Ammer 1992 Trust. Published by
>   Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.

Answer (score 2):

There are many idioms in this general vein. 
One food-related one that seems close to the meaning you want
is ***all sizzle and no steak***:

> [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/all_sizzle_and_no_steak):
>
>   A thing or person which fails to measure up to its description
>     or advanced promotion.
>   *Her latest novel is **all sizzle and no steak.***
>
> [Idioms by The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/all+sizzle+and+no+steak):
>
>   Disappointing or anticlimactic. 
>     Having an exciting, promising, important, or aggrandizing buildup
>     that proves to be unwarranted.
>   - Everyone is in a panic over the supposed water shortages,
>       but personally I think the whole thing is all sizzle and no steak.
>
>     The film had a lot of hype before its release,
>       but after seeing it, I think it’s all sizzle and no steak.

Since you’ve expressed your question in terms of food
*in two different ways*,
I’m not sure what broader, generic meaning you really want. 
Consider ***smoke and mirrors***:

> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_and_mirrors):
>
>   **Smoke and mirrors**
>   is an idiom for a deceptive, fraudulent
>     or insubstantial explanation or description. …
>
> [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Smoke%20and%20Mirrors):
>
> 1. Something/Someone that deceives or distorts the truth.
>
>    Something/Someone that distorts or blurs facts, figures, etc.,
>      like a magic or conjuring work; artful deception; tricky inventiveness.
>
> [Idioms by The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/smoke+and+mirrors):
>
>   deception and confusion. 
>     (Said of statements or more complicated rhetoric
>     used to mislead people rather than inform. 
>     Alludes to the way a magician uses optical illusion
>     to create believability while performing a trick.  Fixed order.)
>   - Most people know that the politician was just using smoke and mirrors
>       to make things look better than they really were.
>
>     Her report was little more than smoke and mirrors. 
>       No one will believe any of it.

Comment: Talking of smoke, I've seen `all smoke, no fire` being used somewhat in this sense too though I am not able to find any online dictionary definitions/references.